# AWS Glue Dynamic Frame columns from array

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a nested json, structured as the following example:
{'A':[{'key':'B','value':'C'},{'key':'D','value':'E'}]}
Now I want to map this to the following schema:

```
|--A 
|--|--B
|--|--D
```

e.g. A structure recovered from a json like:

```
{'A':{'B':'C','D':'E'}}
```

The array in 'A' has no fixed number of entries, but the contained dicts always have the two keys 'key','value'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the script below.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, explode, create_map, collect_list
from itertools import chain

>>> sample.printSchema()
root
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)


>>> final_df = (sample
...             .select(explode('A').alias("A"))
...             .withColumn("A",create_map("A.key", "A.value"))
...             .groupby().agg(collect_list("A").alias("A"))
... )
>>> final_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

>>> final_df.show(truncate=False)
+--------------------+
|A                   |
+--------------------+
|[[B -> C], [D -> E]]|
+--------------------+

>>> (final_df
...  .write
...  .format("json")
...  .mode("overwrite")
...  .save("sample_files/2020-09-29/out")
... )
```

Comment: If I execute your code i get the following json:
 {"A":[{"key":"B","value":"D"},{"key":"D","value":"E"}]}

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps a lot! I can't upvote it since my reputation is yet below 15.

Comment: So I ran into new problems, whilst this works great in pyspark, it happens to fail if I use it in awsglue. The dataFrame looks like this:
`|1        |[[liability -> true], [partially_comprehensive -> true],..` 
if I now convert it to a Dynamic Frame and save it and try to crawl it I get an empty table. Can aws glue not handle mapType columns?

Comment: Getting an empty table can be due to two reasons. Either the underling s3 objects are empty or the crawler in unable to parse the objects. Are you able to see the records in the file when you use s3 select  ?

Comment: So I checked what happens when I write locally with spark to jsons. I then get, instead of the mappings as in the dataframe, entries like :`{"org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@312b0a80":["true"]}`, I think those could cause the crawler to fail. Also I have no clue from where they come from

Comment: what spark version are you using?  You may trying explicity getting the column key and value with 
```python
.select(explode('A').alias("A"))
.selectExpr("A.key as key" , "A.value as value")
.groupby().agg(collect_list(create_map("key", "value")).alias("A"))     
```